# Where do I get tier 3 (Survival affinity) promotion item Forest-Honey Cake?

Tags: star-wars-assault-team

I've been trying to promote both my Wookie and Tarentatek to tier 4 but they both need Forest-Honey cakes to promote.

As Forest-Honey Cake is only a tier-3 promotion item (green color), I've played the Survival Promotion Mission (epic difficulty) in Special Missions multiple times but yet to come across a single Forest-Honey Cake, but have had repeats of other green promotion items.

Has anyone gotten a single Forest-Hony Cake from the above mission? If not, where did you get the promotion item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer to my question. Just keep on doing survival promotion mission (epic) and eventually Forest-honey cake would drop. It did for me, twice in quite a short span of time after not dropping even once for a long time.